# Question about $p$-adic absolute value

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, algebraic-number-theory, absolute-value, p-adic-number-theory

Let $x,y \in \Bbb{Q}^×$, and for $\varepsilon＞0$, suppose $|x-y|_p＜\varepsilon$, where $| \ \ |_p$ is the $p$-adic absolute value.

My book says that if $\varepsilon$ is small enough, then $|y|_p＞(1/2)|x|_p$.

I think this seems obvious because $|y|_p$ and $|x|_p$ are close enough, so half of $|x|_p$ is smaller than $|y|_p$.
But for what $t > 0$ does the condition that $\varepsilon ＜t$ imply $|y|_p ＞ (1/2)|x|_p$ when $|x-y|_p < \varepsilon$? I want to know what can be used for $t$.

Comment: I rewrote the title of the question (which was absurd and too long in its original form) and cleaned up the weird LaTeX code in the body of the question. I hope it still reflects what you were asking, but in a way that will be less confusing for people to read.

Comment: Is $\mathbb{Q}^\times$ the set of positive rationals?

Comment: @fractalletter: It is quite common in ring theory to call $R^\times$ the group of units i.e. multiplicatively invertible elements of a ring $R$. (Or just the underlying set of that group.) In particular, for $K$ a field like here, $K^\times$ is a somewhat neat way to write $ K \setminus \{0 \}$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I use $|\cdot|$ as the usual p-adic absolute value. There is no $t>0$ such that $\varepsilon < t$ implies $|y| >\frac{1}{2}|x|$ when $|x-y|<\varepsilon$. If there were, we could pick a sufficiently large $k$ so that $\varepsilon=p^{-k}$. Next I pick $x=p^{k+1}$, $y=p^{k+2}$ that satisfies $|x-y|=p^{-k-1} < \varepsilon$ and yet, $p^{-k-2}>\frac{1}{2}p^{-k-1}$ implies $2>p$ which is false.

Additionally as a suggestion to amend your question, for every fixed $x \in \mathbb{Q}^\times$ we can pick $\varepsilon<|x|$, and this will give us $|y|=|y-x+x|\le\max(|x-y|,|x|)$ by the ultrametric inequality. However because $|x-y|<\varepsilon < |x|$ we have that the ultrametric inequality's strong property upgrades it into an equality because $|x-y| \ne |x|$. So it becomes $|y|=|y-x+x|=\max(|x-y|,|x|)=|x|$. Now that we know $|y|=|x|$ we easily see $|y|>\frac{1}{2}|x|$.

Comment: Do you mean my book's statement is false ?

Comment: I don't think you're being fair in your interpretation of the book's statement: the result is true for each nonzero $x$, so we should expect $t$ to depend on $x$,  just as we can visualize this on the real line with its standard absolute value.

Comment: @buoyant I added a bit of extra discussion to the question to help clarify what the book probably meant, hope that helps.